# Mysql - Seeing if a value already exist

Tags: php, mysql

i just want to know how I can fix this. In my database : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjo4F.png) i have a value of 123. My code is searching for it however it does not find it.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <?php
        $userid = 123;
        $con = mysqli_connect("","","*","");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }else{
            echo "Connected";
          }
          echo "123";
        // Perform queries
        $sql_fetch_id = "SELECT * FROM AccessedIds WHERE 64id = '123";
        $query_id = mysqli_query(sql2242953, $sql_fetch_id);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_id) ==0) {
            echo "empty";
        }else{
            echo "full";
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 </body>
</html>
```

[Data types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z384K.png)

Comment: I forget...is `64id` a valid identifier? (Generally identifiers have to start with a letter.) If not, you'll need to backquote it.

Comment: Im new arround, i think your askins if its a number;its just like a 12 long number

Comment: Why do you have the single quote mark before 123?

Comment: oh let me change now

Comment: Nope it still returns this:Connected123empty

Comment: What is the data type of the I'd? Show your schema.

Comment: What if you put single quotes before and after 123?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong, try:

```
$query_id = mysqli_query($con, $sql_fetch_id);
```

[More information](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

Also as in the comments above, remove the single quote mark before 123.

Answer (score 0):

Your Query and Query string is wrong. You are missing a Single Quote (') in your Query string. See the below statements:

```
$sql_fetch_id = "SELECT * FROM `AccessedIds` WHERE `64id` = '123'";
$query_id = mysqli_query($con, $sql_fetch_id);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah but you missed out the query string part which I pointed out while you included that about a min ago :)

Comment: Yes, but the OP modified the script, as you can see in the comments. However my query string part is different than yours.